# Calling javascript console API in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am making an extension for a website with react. The website provides API's in the javascript console I can call, like foo().

In vanillas JS I can simply write foo() in my code.

But in React i will get an error "foo is not defined". How can i do this in react?

Comment: Seems to me an error with calling a function that hasn't been declared/defined. What if you define the foo function as anything you like and then do a `foo()` again? What happens?

Comment: @OreoluwaAboluwarin foo() is a function provided by the website that I can directly call in the javascript console. I can call it directly with foo() in vanilla JS but how do I call it with React?

Comment: The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown why you get  "foo is not defined". Nobody but you knows what this website is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

So I learned this is called Scope. Say a website lets you perform foo() on the webpage's javascript console, you can access foo() in your code with

```
const foo = window.foo;
foo();
```